# Fonts used on Android OS Gallery

Tags: android

What fonts / sizes are used for the date, gallery name, and number of items when viewing a gallery on the Android OS?

Comment: fonts and the default font size can vary based on the phone model.

Answer (score 1):

Generally fonts are droid. You can find them in android sources. With ICS the font is now Roboto ;)

Comment: Thanks, they are located under: android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\fonts (this is for android api 10).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I listed all of the fonts here: https://www.quora.com/Android-Development/What-system-fonts-ship-with-Android-versions-2-x-4-x